# D3 word wrapping in zoomable treemap

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hello I have been trying to figure out lately how to wrap svg text in their parent rect in a zoomable treemap (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) just like this guy figured it out with a classic treemap: http://bl.ocks.org/mundhradevang/1387786

Nothing really work, I get an error or 0 everytime I use getBBox...
Anyone manage to wrap text in zoomable treemap ?

Thank you for your time guys

Comment: You need to call `.getBBox()` after the rendering is complete. In particular, if you're using a transition, you need to call it after the transition has finished.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer
I have been trying to place my wrap function somewhere else after my display function , still got 0, do you know anyway of knowing if my elements are already rendered or not ?

Comment: Try disabling all transitions/animations.

Comment: I figured out another way as I could not do without transitions. I killed my label to 6 char and then display the whole as hover.
Thank you for your time & advice though